# Oregano plant leaves drying up

Tags: diagnosis, leaves

I had bought this oregano from a store and had repotted it in a slightly bigger pot. The leaves had dry edges at the store. I kept it in shade for a week then kept it in full sun. After some days some twigs are drying up and leaf edges are still dry. What is the issue? Too much sun? Too damp? The potting mix is 40:40:30 Perlite Cocopeat and Vermicompost.

Location: Delhi, India.

[image]

[image]